# KeyboardDatePickerExample: Onchange set date as moment.utc() in State, when rendering display as moment.local() in React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { moment } from "moment";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
function KeyboardDatePickerExample(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);

  const handleDateChangeMethod = (date) => {
    //store in state moment date as date.utc();
    handleDateChange(date.utc());
    // But this is not setting as date.utc(); instead storing as date.local()
  };

  
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        value={selectedDate && selectedDate.local()}
        onChange={handleDateChangeMethod}
        format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
        ampm={false}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default KeyboardDatePickerExample;
```

// value={selectedDate && selectedDate.local()}

> In the above component "value" date.local() is mutating my state value from date.utc() to date.local()

> I should only display in date.local() but I wanted to store the date in date.utc() format

> In the state I cannot use another state variable to store date as date.utc()

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { moment } from "moment";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
```

> Blockquote: **Setting setDefault UTC will solve the issue**

```
 moment.tz.setDefault("UTC")
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
function KeyboardDatePickerExample(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);

  const handleDateChangeMethod = (date) => {
    //store in state moment date as date.utc();
    handleDateChange(date.utc());
    // But this is not setting as date.utc(); instead storing as date.local()
  };

  
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
```

> Blockquote: **binding value as it is without converting it to local when displaying.**

```
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChangeMethod}
        format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
        ampm={false}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default KeyboardDatePickerExample;
```